# disabling linux tcp receiver window auto tuning

Tags: linux, tcp, performance

I'm working on `linux (2.6.43.8-1.fc15.i686.PAE)` and face some problem to disable auto tuning of the TCP receiver window.

I'm trying to find a given setting that would force my client to advertise a fixed receiver window. I tried to give a same given value to `net.core.rmem_max` (/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max) and `net.core.rmem_default` (/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default) as well as `ipv4.tcp_rmem` (net.ipv4.tcp_rmem) but when checking the advertised window (using wireshark) it's absolutely not changing anything....

This is for a study of TCP behavior and I would be very greatful if someone could answer me

Thanks in advance

PS: I made use of [this post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/) to tune the parameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turn off auto-tuning of the TCP receive buffer size. On the receiver:

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf=0
```

Or

```
$ sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_moderate_rcvbuf
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and clear answer. This gave me also a pointer to [this page](http://www.linuxweblog.com/tuning-tcp-sysctlconf) where all the parameters are extensively explained.

However despite trying both cmd (and still keeping the afore mentioned parameters to the same value) I can observe that the advertised TCP window from my client is increasing (in my experiment I download a 60MB object and start from 17536 win to end at 1049805).

Someone has an idea where this can come from ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this out http://sandilands.info/sgordon/impact-of-bandwidth-delay-product-on-tcp-throughput

Comment: You should disable TCP window scaling *echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling*

Comment: Thanks a lot !

I don't really see the point in disabling the Window scaling I have to say. I tried to disable it anyway, as well as receiver offload, and tested Reno instead of Cubic as congestion control... But it does not work. For small values (1500) I observe the receiver window being fixed at 750 but for high values it does not work.

My goal is to set my client receiver window high enough so that it cannot be the performance bottleneck of my connection. So, fix it to a high value. The window starts being very small and steply increases. Any idea ? Is it possible ?

Comment: what is your client? I meant OS version and application.

Comment: I'm using Fedora 15, for the application I'm not sure what you meant but I'm recording the traffic using tcpdump and read the traces with Wireshark... I could see that when putting a receiver window too big the disabling of the window scaling is overwritten to match the value. I guess it's the best behavior but it may also mean that some other mechanism control the advertised reveiver window and apparently override my settings...

Thanks a lot for you patience and help

Comment: After many search the thing does not seem so easy in fact. I might have found a work around using ip route cmd that could set the originial receiver window size. The bad part is that it's a **per connection** setting:
You might want to have a look at [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/365975/linux-slow-start-changing-ip-route-does-not-have-any-effect-on-initial-window)

Comment: Desactivate receiver windo auto tuning: <br/>
$sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_moderate_rcvbuf <br/>
* Then fixing to 4000000 min/default/max for autotuning <br/>
$sudo echo 4000000 4000000 4000000 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem <br/>
* Fixing to 4000000 rmem_default/max <br/>
$sudo echo 4000000 > /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default <br/>
$sudo echo 4000000 > /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max <br/>
* Overwritting the first value of the advertised receiver window to a value high enough to be over 4MB <br/>
$ip route change default via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 proto static initrwnd 5000

Comment: the 0.0.0.0 is the default gateway addrees (change here) and the window scaling has to be re activated

Comment: `sudo echo foo > xxx` will *never* work as intended because the redirection (>) is done by the shell. Running `echo` as root will not achieve anything. You probably want this instead: `echo foo | sudo tee xxx`.